# Pytorch/cuda : CPU error and map_location

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error

I write this code to download my model :

```
args = parser.parse_args()

use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

state_dict = torch.load(args.model)
model = Net()
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
model.eval()

if use_cuda:
    print('Using GPU')
    model.cuda()
else:
    print('Using CPU')
```

But my terminal returns the following error   `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.`

So then I tried to write without really understanding too much :

```
args = parser.parse_args()

map_location=torch.device('cpu')
state_dict = torch.load(args.model)
model = Net()
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
model.eval()
```

But I still have the same mistake. Do you see please how I can correct it? (actually I want to load my model with my CPU).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you saved the model on a computer with a GPU and are now loading it on a computer without one, or maybe you for some reason the GPU is not available. Also, which line is causing the error?

The parameter `map_location` needs to be set inside `torch.load`. Like this:

```
state_dict = torch.load(args.model, map_location='cpu')
```

or

```
map_location=torch.device('cpu')
state_dict = torch.load(args.model, map_location=map_location)
```

Notice that you need to **send** the map_location variable to the `torch.load` function.